# how to map repeated id in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I have this code, its idea is to save the product in localstorage and when the product is already in localstorage it doesn't make the request again

```
  getItemById(id) {
    // return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`);
    return this.cacheS.getOrSetCache(`StoreService_getItemById_${id}_${this.layout.emp.id}`,  this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`), 300000);
 }


  getOrSetCache(key: string, request: Observable<any>, msToExpire = 3600000): Observable<any> {
    let cache: any = {};
    const keyy = 'StoreService_getItemById_teste';
    cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyy));

    return (cache?.data && (cache?.exp > Date.now())) ?
    of(cache.data) :
    request.pipe(
        tap(v => {
          let arr: any[] = [];
          let string = localStorage.getItem(keyy);
          if (string) arr = JSON.parse(string);
          console.log(arr)

          arr.push({data: v, exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)});
          localStorage.setItem(keyy, JSON.stringify(arr));
       })
    );
}
```

how could i map the ids so that when i already have it in localstorage it doesn't make the request for that id ?

also wanted to know how I could see about the expiration date if the current time is equal to or greater than this timestamp, it removes it from the cache and does the query again

[image]
in the image you can see that it has two repeated ids

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you parse the local storage item, use javascript `find` to check if the array already contains the ID.

```
getItemById(id) {
        // return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`);
        return this.cacheS.getOrSetCache(
            id,
            `StoreService_getItemById_${id}_${this.layout.emp.id}`,
            this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`),
            300000
        );
    }

    getOrSetCache(
        id: any,
        key: string,
        request: Observable<any>,
        msToExpire = 3600000
    ): Observable<any> {
        let cache: any = {};
        const keyy = 'StoreService_getItemById_teste';
        cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyy));
        return (cache?.data && cache?.exp > Date.now()) ||
            (cache?.data && cache?.data.find(item => item.data.id === id))
            ? of(cache.data)
            : request.pipe(
                    tap(v => {
                        let arr: any[] = [];
                        let string = localStorage.getItem(keyy);
                        if (string) arr = JSON.parse(string);
                        console.log(arr);

                        arr.push({ data: v, exp: Date.now() + msToExpire });
                        localStorage.setItem(keyy, JSON.stringify(arr));
                    })
              );
    }
```

Comment: this code doesn't seem to fit very well, it seems that it only takes the first id, but I do 5 times in a row the getItemById request, in the browser it returns
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Comment: I put a console.log(id) in the getItemById request and it only returns an id

Comment: in the code that was returned the 5 ids

Comment: @LeonardoLima answer edited, i added the null check for the first comment, the provided code will ensure the API call doesn't happen for the Id, please debug this solution

Comment: keeps saving repeated ids inside localstorage, I think the code is not able to access the array objects  
I updated the question with a print of the local storage